# Photoshop add metallic shine to .png file turned 3D

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, metallic

I'm new to photoshop and working on creating a 3D text based logo. The logo is in a png file and I have already adjusted the 3D to how I want. I want to give it a metallic shine though.

I looked through the properties and there's the premade textures but the logo I'm working with already has a specific color of `#e36e20` so I would like to keep that same color, while giving it a metallic look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you simply want to change the color of the metallic and you're working on a PNG, you could start by creating a normal silver metallic. There's many tutorials for this.

Then you could simply add a layer with your color, and choose a blending mode to colorize it. You can add a layer mask to that layer to keep your transparency. Explore the different modes, maybe there's one you'll prefer and you can also play with the transparency of that colored layer too for different effects or less saturation.

If you want to simply create your own gradient with the right color values, you can still use the blending mode suggested above to select the matching colors for your gradient; at least you'll know what colors to use and then how to customize the premade texture, if it's possible.

You can use the color picker tool in Photoshop and get the different Hex recipes to apply them to any silver effect tutorial instead of the grays.

---

## Here's some examples:

**Original**

[image: Silver metal effect]

**With a layer using blending mode "Overlay"**

[image: Copper metal effect orange overlay]

**With a layer using blending more "Color"**

[image: Copper metal effect orange color]

**With a layer using blending more "Vivid Light"**

[image: Copper metal effect orange vivid]